# Error webpage unavailable in Hybris HMC/MCC webpage unavailable after successful login in HMC/MCC

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am able to get HMC/MCC login screen but when I login it says Webpage unavailable.
My Hybris version is 6.2

My localextension.xml files looks like below :

```
     <extension dir="C:\Hybris620\hybris\bin/custom/training/trainingfulfilmentprocess"/>
     <extension dir="C:\Hybris620\hybris\bin/custom/training/trainingcore"/>
     <extension dir="C:\Hybris620\hybris\bin/custom/training/traininginitialdata"/>
     <extension dir="C:\Hybris620\hybris\bin/custom/training/trainingfacades"/>
     <extension dir="C:\Hybris620\hybris\bin/custom/training/trainingtest"/>
     <extension dir="C:\Hybris620\hybris\bin/custom/training/trainingstorefront"/>
     <extension dir="C:\Hybris620\hybris\bin/custom/training/trainingcockpits"/>
```

Also I am able to open all Hybris URL's except HMC/MCC

My local properties file looks like below :

```
# place your custom properties into this file instead of modifying the project.properties

# all properties in this file have higher `enter code here`priority and will overwrite the platform/project.properties settings.


mykey=myvalue

solrserver.instances.default.autostart=false


#hac.webroot=/hac
```

Also my Hybris initialization did not go well . It was stuck in Localizing types phase for hours.

I tried below resolution steps with no luck :

1. Adding mcc and hmc extensions in localextensions xml file
2. Adding hac.webroot=/hac and hmc.webroot=/hmc in local properties file

Comment: I am able to get MCC/HMC login screen but after login there is a message webpage unavailable

Comment: Can you please check and share the logs, you will get the logs in hybris/log/ folder.

Comment: Let me know your email id I will send you the log file.

Comment: @Ashishjha Please post the log file in the question, so other people are able to help you also.

Answer (score 2):

HMC is now deprecated and would not automatically be added in localextenion.xml once you setup any accelerator using recipe in Hybris 6.2

You need to add these extension in you localextension.xml and finally do System Update.

```
<extension name="hmc" />
<extension name='platformhmc' />
<extension name='solrfacetsearchhmc' />
<extension name='commercesearchhmc' />
<extension name='platformhmc' />
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the hmc and mcc you need to add the extensions in your `localextensions.xml` (for hmc you can remove some extensions depending on your needs)

- hmc
- platformhmc
- printhmc
- bmecathmc
- classificationsystemshmc
- solrfacetsearchhmc
- lucenesearchhmc
- subscriptionserviceshmc
- timedaccesspromotionshmc
- mcc

Then you must end the initialization with success.

For that, if you use HSQLDB you **must** use more than one processor on your computer or the init will be stuck forever on "localizing type". If you can't add processor, you'll have to switch to another DB (mysql for example).

Answer (score 0):

Yes now I am able to login inside Hybris HMC but I am able to see any folders inside it.