# HMC not showing up in hybris 6.2

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, cockpit

i have installed the b2c recipe using https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/8c46c266866910149666a0fe4caeee4e.html those instructions.But when i try to go into the hmc using https://localhost:9001/hmc/hybris .It gets redircted to the hac .I am not sure what is going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281677/error-webpage-unavailable-in-hybris-hmc-mcc-webpage-unavailable-after-successful

Comment: Hybris does not ship HMC now with recipes as it's deprecated. You need to manually add relevant extensions into localextension.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in Shreshtt Bhatt comment, the hMC is [deprecated](https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/8bb15ed586691014a948d1553f4947cf.html).

From the [hMC documentation](https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/8bca888b86691014abfbaf7b92c133f0.html)

> The last version of SAP Hybris Commerce containing the Hybris Management Console (HMC) will be released with the Q4 2017 release. All HMC-related extensions (hmc, platformhmc, printhmc, bmecathmc, classificationsystemshmc, solrfacetsearchhmc, lucenesearchhmc, subscriptionserviceshmc, timedaccesspromotionshmc) will be removed from the Hybris distribution ZIP file with the Q1 2018 release.

If you want to enable it you'll have to add in your `localextensions.xml` file the list of extensions you want to use in your hmc (the list is present above).